# jQuery is not defined in SPFx extension

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, spfx-extensions

I have created SPFx extension (not a webpart, in case it makes any difference) and trying to add jQuery but its not doing it.
I have installed it into package with
`npm install --save @types/jquery`
added

```
"externals": {
      "jquery": "./src/extensions/tracker2/js/JQuery_3.5.1.js"
  },
```

into config.json ,
`import * as jQuery from 'jquery';`
into MyPackage.ts
But still getting " jQuery is not defined " when trying to use jQuery in my code.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with a small 'q' => jquery ?

Comment: Just a little addition - I am using external js file:         
extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<ITracker2ApplicationCustomizerProperties> {
   private _JS: string = "https://MyTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/DevHubSite/SiteAssets/CustomJS/Tracker.js";
    

  @override
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
       
    let articleRedirectScriptTag: HTMLScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
       articleRedirectScriptTag.src = this._JS;
       articleRedirectScriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
       document.body.appendChild(articleRedirectScriptTag);"

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you din't isntall jquery.

`@types/jquery` package does not actually contain jQuery. All packages that start with @types prefix are merely definition files that help your TypeScript to have intellisese.

In install jquery you need `jquery` package:

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Then, to use the package:

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

**Update**

I have read [the Official MS documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/add-an-external-library) and they are using the following link:

"jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"

Perhaps, if you update the link and then run the following commands, the error will go away:

```
gulp clean
gulp build
```

Comment: Tried it - still not defined :(

Answer (score 0):

I tried your method in an extension, here it works fine.

[image]
[image]

Can you have a check if the referenced path/filename is correct? And you can check if jquery file has been loaded or not using F12.

[image]

BR

Comment: I tried same setup you showed and its still not working, JQuery file is not loading (its not there when I check by pressing F12) :(

Answer (score 0):

Started working when I added one line with jQuery into "public onInit()"
As I mentioned I have one js file that I import with
"let articleRedirectScriptTag: HTMLScriptElement = document.createElement("script");"
In which I also have some jquey.
Thanks for all your replies.